# Understanding explicit type casts in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datepart

```
WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN CAST(DATE_PART('Year', now()) AS CHAR(4))+ '0101'
```

I want to get the current year and adding to this year the month and the day. When I run the query, I run into below error. Did anyone experience this before?

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: character + unknown
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: In Postgresql `+` is not the concatenation operator. Use `||` or the function CONCAT().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method seems really arcane to me.  Two alternatives:

```
WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY') || '0101'

WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', NOW()), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Comment: WHEN 'H' = 'E' THEN TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'YYYY') || '0101' This alternative solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to add a numeric value with a text, and it is not allowed. To create dates use `make_date`:

```
SELECT 
  make_date(date_part('year', now())::int,01,01),
  make_date(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())::int,01,01),
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())||'0101'; -- in case you just need a string 

 make_date  | make_date  | ?column? 
------------+------------+----------
 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 20210101
```